# Write text on an image in C#

Tags: c#, image, text, draw

I have the following problem. I want to make some graphics in bitmap image like bond form

i can write a text in image
but i will write more text in various positions

```
Bitmap a = new Bitmap(@"path\picture.bmp");

using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(a))
{
    g.DrawString(....); // requires font, brush etc
}
```

How can I write text and save it, and write another text in saved image.

Comment: What is your question? What problem are you having?

Comment: You have added a question, but didn't describe the actual problem you are having with doing this.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

To draw multiple strings, call `graphics.DrawString` multiple times. You can specify the location of the drawn string. This example we will draw two strings "Hello", "Word" ("Hello" in blue color upfront "Word" in red color):

```
string firstText = "Hello";
string secondText = "World";

PointF firstLocation = new PointF(10f, 10f);
PointF secondLocation = new PointF(10f, 50f);

string imageFilePath = @"path\picture.bmp"
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(imageFilePath);//load the image file

using(Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
{
    using (Font arialFont =  new Font("Arial", 10))
    {
        graphics.DrawString(firstText, arialFont, Brushes.Blue, firstLocation);
        graphics.DrawString(secondText, arialFont, Brushes.Red, secondLocation);
    }
}

bitmap.Save(imageFilePath);//save the image file
```

**Edit:** "I Add a load and save code".

You can open the bitmap file any time `Image.FromFile`, and draw a new text on it using the above code. and then save the image file `bitmap.Save`

Comment: @wahab: check the answer edits. is that what you are asking for?

Comment: @wahab: This is usually a problem in the file path. check your file path, a correct path looks like: `string path = @"C:\my image.bmp";

Comment: using(Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
{
    using (Font arialFont =  new Font("Arial", 10)
    {
        graphics.DrawString(firstText, arialFont, Brushes.Blue, firstLocation);

             bitmap.Save(newpath);//save the image file

        graphics.DrawString(secondText, arialFont, Brushes.Red, secondLocation);


            bitmap.Save(newpath);//save the image file
    }
}
 it worked

Comment: @wahab: Glad it worked for you :) don't forget to mark the answer as the [accepted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) if it answers your question.

Comment: And write text with background color in image ?

Comment: @Kiquenet you can fill rectangle with your prefaired color, like using the graphics object in the example, so `graphics.FillRectangle(yourBackgroundSize ....); then graphics.DrawString(....)`

Comment: I had to read the first phrase of your first sentence and I still don't understand it

Comment: @LocustHorde To draw multiple `strings` in which each `string` need to be located at different place or `Point` within a given `Image`, you need to call the `graphics.DrawString` function multiple times and specify the location for each of those strings.

Comment: Thanks! much better now

Comment: @JamshaidKamran: yes, background-less png means image with Alpha channel, you can load/create image with alpha channel (32bit as 8 bits for alpha) and draw on top of it using the above..

Comment: The one thing missing from all these answers is "How do I know if the string will fit?" (or "How can I fit the bitmap to the string perfectly?"). The answer is to use [Graphics.MeasureString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.measurestring?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 7):

Here's an example of a call to [`Graphics.DrawString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76c5db29.aspx), taken from [here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-snippet-tutorial-how-to-draw-text-on-an-image):

```
g.DrawString("My\nText", new Font("Tahoma", 40), Brushes.White, new PointF(0, 0));
```

It obviously relys on having a font called `Tahoma` installed.

The `Brushes` class has many built-in brushes.

See also, the MSDN page for [`Graphics.DrawString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76c5db29.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

To save changes to the same file, I had to combine [Jalal Said](https://stackoverflow.com/users/323339/jalal-said)'s answer and [NSGaga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/417747/nsgaga)'s answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15862810/a-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi-in-bitmap-save-method) question. You need to create a new *Bitmap* object based on the old one, dispose old *Bitmap* object, then save using the new object:

```
string firstText = "Hello";
string secondText = "World";

PointF firstLocation = new PointF(10f, 10f);
PointF secondLocation = new PointF(10f, 50f);

string imageFilePath = @"path\picture.bmp";

Bitmap newBitmap;
using (var bitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(imageFilePath))//load the image file
{
    using(Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {
        using (Font arialFont =  new Font("Arial", 10))
        {
            graphics.DrawString(firstText, arialFont, Brushes.Blue, firstLocation);
            graphics.DrawString(secondText, arialFont, Brushes.Red, secondLocation);
        }
    }
    newBitmap = new Bitmap(bitmap);
}

newBitmap.Save(imageFilePath);//save the image file
newBitmap.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    public string imageFilePath = null;
    public string textOnImage = null;

    public Image baseImage;
    public Image modifiedImage;

    public int xcoOrdinate = 0;
    public int ycoOrdinate = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonLoadImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            OpenFileDialog uploadfileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            uploadfileDialog.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*";
            uploadfileDialog.Multiselect = false;

            if (uploadfileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                imageFilePath = uploadfileDialog.FileName;
            }

            baseImage = Image.FromFile(imageFilePath);
            modifiedImage = (Image)baseImage.Clone();
            pictureBoxToShowPic.Image = baseImage;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Source + " : " + ex.Message);
        }            
    }

    public void paint()
    {
        try
        {
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(modifiedImage);
            using (Font myfont = new Font("Arial", 14))
            {
                var format = new StringFormat
                {
                    Alignment = StringAlignment.Center,
                    LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
                };

                g.DrawString(textOnImage, myfont, Brushes.Black, new Point(xcoOrdinate, ycoOrdinate), format);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Source + " : " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void buttonAddText_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            textOnImage = textBoxWriteText.Text;
            paint();
            pictureBoxToShowPic.Image = modifiedImage;
            pictureBoxToShowPic.Refresh();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Source + " : " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void pictureBoxToShowPic_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            xcoOrdinate = e.X;
            ycoOrdinate = e.Y;
        }            
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Source + " : " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void buttonSaveImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SaveFileDialog savefileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();

            savefileDialog.Filter = "Images|*.jpg ; *.png ; *.bmp";

            if (savefileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                imageFilePath = savefileDialog.FileName;
            }

            modifiedImage.Save(imageFilePath);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Source + " : " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I found a more suitable solution and this one works for me. By this one, we can add text dynamically in various positions. Double Click on the image, where you want to add text. Remember that keep your picture size property normal, otherwise, with the mouse position, the original position where you want to add text is not detected. And by this solution, you can save the modified image properly.

Answer (score -8):

If Someone has trouble with this  code lines:

```
using(Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
```

The solution is :

```
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)**System.Drawing.Image.FromFile**(@"C:\Documents and Settings\", true);
```

Comment: What problem is this supposed to solve? The original line of code is simple and clear and should work. The new line of code... I'm not even clear on what it does, and I certainly can't tell why.