# Adding text to a JPG image in ASP.net C# and save to file on server

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, drawstring

I'm using the following code (credit to Dolph Larson) to take a pre-made image file in bitmap format on an ASP.net server, draw a string on it and save it to file on the server.  In the original code, he dumps the bitmap to the OutputStream, but I'd like to dump it instead to a file.

The version of code below successfully creates the new file, but when I open it, the string does not appear drawn on the image in the new file.  I imagine I am missing a step -- when I use bitMapImage.Save("bitmaptest.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg) am I just re-saving the original instead of the modified version?

Here is the code:

```
        //Load the Image to be written on.
        Bitmap bitMapImage = new
        System.Drawing.Bitmap(Server.MapPath("generic.jpg"));
        Graphics graphicImage = Graphics.FromImage(bitMapImage);
        graphicImage.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        graphicImage.DrawString("testing 1 2 3",
        new Font("Arial", 20, FontStyle.Bold),
        SystemBrushes.WindowText, new Point(0, 0));
        Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        bitMapImage.Save("bitmaptest.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        graphicImage.Dispose();
        bitMapImage.Dispose();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems to me you should save the graphics' bitmap, not the bitmap you took the image from... in other words, graphicImage might be modifying it's own copy of the  BitmapImage, and you are saving the original one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works just fine; You simply need to specify the path where you want to save the image:

Example:

```
//Load the Image to be written on.
        Bitmap bitMapImage = new
        System.Drawing.Bitmap((@"c:\\foo\\generic.jpg"));
        Graphics graphicImage = Graphics.FromImage(bitMapImage);
        graphicImage.DrawString("testing 1 2 3",
        new Font("Arial", 20, FontStyle.Bold),
        SystemBrushes.WindowText, new Point(0, 0)); 
        bitMapImage.Save("c:\\foo\\bitmaptest.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        graphicImage.Dispose();
        bitMapImage.Dispose();
```

**Note** In your case, bitMapImage.Save needs to be as follows: `bitMapImage.Save(Server.MapPath("~/Images")+"newImage.jpg",ImageFormat.Jpeg);` since you are attempting to save the image on an asp.net app. `~/Images` in my example is just the virtual directory `Images` inside your app.

Comment: It works!  I changed the color to a solid blue bitmap and there was my text!  Duh, as they say.  Oddly enough the image I was writing on has a white background but the text didn't seem to appear.  Maybe there is some issue with my image, I'll resave and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Yes ..You are saving the same image .You have to create a ne wbitmap and save it:-

```
Bitmap bitMapNew = Bitmap.FromHbitmap(graphicImage.GetHdc());
bitMapNew.Save("bitmaptest.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Add these lines instead of your bitMapImage.save

Comment: I'm getting am error that states "A generic error occurred in the GDI+" on the first line.  I've looked a little online and it sounds like it may be a bug, have you encountered it before?

Comment: It should be a problem with your path.Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826921/write-text-on-an-image-in-c-sharp

Comment: Thanks again for all of your help and replying, I will see if I can get it to work both ways.