# A Generic error occurred in GDI+ in Bitmap.Save method

Tags: c#, gdi+, system.drawing

I am working on to upload and save a thumbnail copy of that image in a thumbnail folder.

I am using following link:

http://weblogs.asp.net/markmcdonnell/archive/2008/03/09/resize-image-before-uploading-to-server.aspx

but

```
newBMP.Save(directory + "tn_" + filename);
```

is causing exception "A generic error occurred in GDI+."

I have tried to give permission on folder, also tried to use a new separate bmp object when saving.

**Edit:**

```
    protected void ResizeAndSave(PropBannerImage objPropBannerImage)
    {
        // Create a bitmap of the content of the fileUpload control in memory
        Bitmap originalBMP = new Bitmap(fuImage.FileContent);

        // Calculate the new image dimensions
        int origWidth = originalBMP.Width;
        int origHeight = originalBMP.Height;
        int sngRatio = origWidth / origHeight;
        int thumbWidth = 100;
        int thumbHeight = thumbWidth / sngRatio;

        int bannerWidth = 100;
        int bannerHeight = bannerWidth / sngRatio;

        // Create a new bitmap which will hold the previous resized bitmap
        Bitmap thumbBMP = new Bitmap(originalBMP, thumbWidth, thumbHeight);
        Bitmap bannerBMP = new Bitmap(originalBMP, bannerWidth, bannerHeight);

        // Create a graphic based on the new bitmap
        Graphics oGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(thumbBMP);
        // Set the properties for the new graphic file
        oGraphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias; oGraphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

        // Draw the new graphic based on the resized bitmap
        oGraphics.DrawImage(originalBMP, 0, 0, thumbWidth, thumbHeight);

        Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(thumbBMP);
        thumbBMP.Dispose();
        thumbBMP = null;

        // Save the new graphic file to the server
        newBitmap.Save("~/image/thumbs/" + "t" + objPropBannerImage.ImageId, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

        oGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(bannerBMP);
        // Set the properties for the new graphic file
        oGraphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias; oGraphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

        // Draw the new graphic based on the resized bitmap
        oGraphics.DrawImage(originalBMP, 0, 0, bannerWidth, bannerHeight);
        // Save the new graphic file to the server
        bannerBMP.Save("~/image/" + objPropBannerImage.ImageId + ".jpg");


        // Once finished with the bitmap objects, we deallocate them.
        originalBMP.Dispose();

        bannerBMP.Dispose();
        oGraphics.Dispose();
    }
```

Answer (score 121, accepted):

> When either a Bitmap object or an Image object is constructed from a
>   file, the file remains locked for the lifetime of the object. As a
>   result, you cannot change an image and save it back to the same file
>   where it originated.
>   http://support.microsoft.com/?id=814675

[A generic error occurred in GDI+, JPEG Image to MemoryStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053052/a-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi-jpeg-image-to-memorystream/1053123#1053123)

[Image.Save(..) throws a GDI+ exception because the memory stream is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336387/image-save-throws-a-gdi-exception-because-the-memory-stream-is-closed/336396#336396)

http://alperguc.blogspot.in/2008/11/c-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi.html

**EDIT:**
just writing from memory...

> save to an 'intermediary' memory stream, that should work

e.g. try this one - replace

```
    Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(thumbBMP);
    thumbBMP.Dispose();
    thumbBMP = null;
    newBitmap.Save("~/image/thumbs/" + "t" + objPropBannerImage.ImageId, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

with something like:

```
string outputFileName = "...";
using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(outputFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
    {
        thumbBMP.Save(memory, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        byte[] bytes = memory.ToArray();
        fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, using these i got it working. I am posting the code working again.

Comment: A related issue, maybe it will help someone - I got the "A Generic error occured in GDI+" on _opening_ a bitmap already. And only on a remote webserver, not on my local test machine. Turns out that the GDI+ present on Azure IIS servers can't handle new format BMPs generated by GIMP. I had to either a) resave BMP with Paint b) use an uncompressed PNG instead c) save as 24bit BMP with GIMP (worse quality)

Comment: Not sure what I was doing wrong in a project I was tinkering with... but for some reason, the MemoryStream/FileStream combo worked for me (with minor variations to account for my particular method call). Here's a +1 for a 5 year old post.

Comment: @WernerCD I know, the problem (and the fix) is a bit counterintuitive - but the oversimplified explanation underlying this (in many cases, depending on the specifics) is that you need to break away from the original bitmap object (and its references), and memory stream helps with that.

Comment: @NSGaga Well I was using MS's (I pulled a file from a PDF into an Bitmap/Image object)... but when I tried to pull that Bitmap/Image object out and put it onto the disk it was crapping itself. The `Memory /FileStream` vs `bitmap.Save(...)` is I think the counter-intuitive step that worked for me. I think. Irregardless, this gave me the push I was looking for after HOURS of circling the problem.

Answer (score 67):

This error message is displayed if the path you pass to `Bitmap.Save()` is invalid (folder doesn't exist etc).

Comment: certainly this was the case with me, I up voted it so no one else should waste any further time. also make sure your path does include filename as well.

Comment: For me the path did exist, but it didn't have the necessary permissions to write to the folder.

Answer (score 19):

```
    // Once finished with the bitmap objects, we deallocate them.
    originalBMP.Dispose();

    bannerBMP.Dispose();
    oGraphics.Dispose();
```

This is a programming style that you'll regret sooner or later.  Sooner is knocking on the door, you forgot one.  You are not disposing *newBitmap*.  Which keeps a lock on the file until the garbage collector runs.  If it doesn't run then the second time you try to save to the same file you'll get the klaboom.  GDI+ exceptions are too miserable to give a good diagnostic so serious head-scratching ensues.  Beyond the thousands of googlable posts that mention this mistake.

**Always** favor using the *using* statement.  Which never forgets to dispose an object, even if the code throws an exception.

```
using (var newBitmap = new Bitmap(thumbBMP)) {
    newBitmap.Save("~/image/thumbs/" + "t" + objPropBannerImage.ImageId, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

Albeit that it is very unclear why you even create a new bitmap, saving thumbBMP should already be good enough.  Anyhoo, give the rest of your disposable objects the same using love.

Answer (score 9):

In my case **the bitmap image file already existed in the system drive**, so my app threw the error **"A Generic error occured in GDI+"**.

1. Verify that the destination folder exists
2. Verify that there isn't already a file with the same name in the destination folder

Answer (score 6):

Check your folder's permission where the image is saved 
Right cLick on folder then go :

> Properties > Security > Edit > Add-- select "everyone" and check Allow "Full Control"

Comment: This is a horrible practice, you should never give global full control!

Answer (score 6):

I was facing the same issue **A generic error occurred in GDI+** on saving while working on MVC app, I was getting this error because I was writing wrong path to save image, I **corrected saving path** and it worked fine for me.

```
img1.Save(Server.MapPath("/Upload/test.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);


--Above code need one change, as you need to put close brackets on Server.MapPath() method after writing its param.
```

Like this-

```
img1.Save(Server.MapPath("/Upload/test.png"), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

Answer (score 4):

GDI+ exceptions occured due to below points

1. Folder access issue
2. Missing properties of images

If folder issue - please provide access to application
If Missing properties then use below code

**Code 1**

```
using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(webStream))
{
     using (Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(bmp))
     {
         newImage.Save("c:\temp\test.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
     }
}
```

**Code 2**

```
using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(webStream))
{

     using (Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(bmp))
     {
        newImage.SetResolution(bmp.HorizontalResolution, bmp.VerticalResolution);
        Rectangle lockedRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
        BitmapData bmpData = newImage.LockBits(lockedRect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmp.PixelFormat);
        bmpData.PixelFormat = bmp.PixelFormat;
        newImage.UnlockBits(bmpData);
        using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
         {
             gr.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
             gr.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
             gr.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
         }

         foreach (var item in bmp.PropertyItems)
         {
             newImage.SetPropertyItem(item);
         }
         newImage.Save("c:\temp\test.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
}
```

Different between code 1 and code 2

**Code - 1 :** it will just create image and can open it on normal image viewer

- the image can't open in Photoshop
- Image size will be double

**Code - 2 :** to open image in image edition tools use code

by using code 1 it just create images but it not assign image marks.

Answer (score 3):

I always check/test these:

- Does the path + filename contain illegal characters for the given filesystem?
- Does the file already exist? (Bad)
- Does the path already exist? (Good)
- If the path is relative: am I expecting it in the right parent directory (mostly `bin/Debug` ;-) )?
- Is the path writable for the program and as which user does it run? (Services can be tricky here!)
- Does the full path really, really not contain illegal chars? (some unicode chars are close to invisible)

I never had any problems with `Bitmap.Save()` apart from this list.

Answer (score 2):

I had a different issue with the same exception.

**In short:**

Make sure that the `Bitmap`'s object `Stream` is not being disposed before calling `.Save` .

**Full story:**

There was a method that returned a `Bitmap` object, built from a `MemoryStream` in the following way:

```
private Bitmap getImage(byte[] imageBinaryData){
    .
    .
    .
    Bitmap image;
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(imageBinaryData))
    {
        image = new Bitmap(stream);
    }
    return image;
}
```

then someone used the returned image to save it as a file

```
image.Save(path);
```

The problem was that the original stream was already disposed when trying to save the image, throwing the GDI+ exeption.

A fix to this problem was to return the `Bitmap` without disposing the stream itself but the returned `Bitmap` object.

```
private Bitmap getImage(byte[] imageBinaryData){
   .
   .
   .
   Bitmap image;
   var stream = new MemoryStream(imageBinaryData))
   image = new Bitmap(stream);

   return image;
}
```

then:

```
using (var image = getImage(binData))
{
   image.Save(path);
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer and it is a shame it is buried under the many duplicate answers related to bad path.  The underlying stream cannot be destroyed.  An alternative is to create a new bitmap from the old one: new Bitmap(oldBitmap).Save(...)

Answer (score 1):

I got it working using FileStream, get help from these
http://alperguc.blogspot.in/2008/11/c-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi.html
http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2010/02/resize-image-upload-ms-sql-database.html

```
System.Drawing.Image imageToBeResized = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fuImage.PostedFile.InputStream);
        int imageHeight = imageToBeResized.Height;
        int imageWidth = imageToBeResized.Width;
        int maxHeight = 240;
        int maxWidth = 320;
        imageHeight = (imageHeight * maxWidth) / imageWidth;
        imageWidth = maxWidth;

        if (imageHeight > maxHeight)
        {
            imageWidth = (imageWidth * maxHeight) / imageHeight;
            imageHeight = maxHeight;
        }

        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(imageToBeResized, imageWidth, imageHeight);
        System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        bitmap.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        stream.Position = 0;
        byte[] image = new byte[stream.Length + 1];
        stream.Read(image, 0, image.Length);
        System.IO.FileStream fs
= new System.IO.FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/image/a.jpg"), System.IO.FileMode.Create
, System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            fs.Write(image, 0, image.Length);
```

Answer (score 1):

For me it was a permission problem. Somebody removed write permissions on the folder for the user account under which the application was running.

Answer (score 0):

Create folder path image/thumbs on your hard disk => Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

```
    I used below logic while saving a .png format. This is to ensure the file is already existing or not.. if exist then saving it by adding 1 in the filename

Bitmap btImage = new Bitmap("D:\\Oldfoldername\\filename.png");
    string path="D:\\Newfoldername\\filename.png";
            int Count=0;
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
                {
                    do
                    {
                        path = "D:\\Newfoldername\\filename"+"_"+ ++Count + ".png";                    
                    } while (System.IO.File.Exists(path));
                }

                btImage.Save(path, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error while trying to convert Tiff images to Jpeg. For me the issue stemmed from the tiff dimensions being too large. Anything up to around 62000 pixels was fine, anything above this size produced the error.

Answer (score 0):

for me it was a path issue when saving the image.

```
int count = Directory.EnumerateFiles(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/images/savedimages"), "*").Count();

var img = Base64ToImage(imgRaw);

string path = "images/savedimages/upImages" + (count + 1) + ".png";

img.Save(Path.Combine(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path)));

return path;
```

So I fixed it by adding the following forward slash

```
String path = "images/savedimages....
```

should be

```
String path = "/images/savedimages....
```

Hope that helps anyone stuck!

Answer (score 0):

from msdn: `public void Save (string filename);` which is quite surprising to me because we dont just have to pass in the filename, we have to pass the filename along with the path for example: `MyDirectory/MyImage.jpeg`, here `MyImage.jpeg` does not actually exist yet, but our file will be saved with this name.

Another important point here is that if you are using `Save()` in a web application then use `Server.MapPath()` along with it which basically just returns the physical path for the virtual path which is passed in. Something like: `image.Save(Server.MapPath("~/images/im111.jpeg"));`

Answer (score 0):

I use this solution

```
int G = 0;

private void toolStripMenuItem17_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Directory.CreateDirectory("picture");// هذه العملية للرسم بدون ان يحذف بقية الرسومات
  G = G + 1;
  FormScreen();
  memoryImage1.Save("picture\\picture" + G.ToString() + ".jpg");
  pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("picture\\picture" + G.ToString() + ".jpg");
}
```

Comment: You can just edit your post instead of deleting and re-posting a new one.

Answer (score 0):

The code below solved my problem

```
pictureBox1.Image=myImage;
  
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
bmp.Save("C:\\Users/super/Desktop/robin.jpg");
```