# gdip image save directly intptr in my local drive

Tags: c#, image, scanning, intptr, save-dialog

I have this code to get the image file from the scanner and save it on local disk:

```
                            IntPtr img = (IntPtr)pics[i];
                            SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, false);
                            SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
                            SetStyle(ControlStyles.Opaque, true);
                            SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
                            SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
                            bmprect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
                            bmpptr = GlobalLock(img);
                            pixptr = GetPixelInfo(bmpptr);
                            Gdip.SaveDIBAs(@"C:\", bmpptr, pixptr);
```

The problem is here `Gdip.SaveDIBAs(@"C:\", bmpptr, pixptr);`.the save dialog.
[image]

I want to discard this dialog  and save file directly in my drive.

```
**Updated:**



  public static bool SaveDIBAs(string picname, IntPtr bminfo, IntPtr pixdat)
        {
            SaveFileDialog sd = new SaveFileDialog();

            sd.FileName = picname;
            sd.Title = "Save bitmap as...";
            sd.Filter =
                "Bitmap file (*.bmp)|*.bmp|TIFF file (*.tif)|*.tif|JPEG file (*.jpg)|*.jpg|PNG file (*.png)|*.png|GIF file (*.gif)|*.gif|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            sd.FilterIndex = 1;

            return true;
        }
      for (int i = 0; i < pics.Count; i++)
                            {
                                IntPtr img = (IntPtr)pics[i];


                                SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, false);
                                SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
                                SetStyle(ControlStyles.Opaque, true);
                                SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
                                SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);

                                bmprect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);

                                bmpptr = GlobalLock(img);
                                pixptr = GetPixelInfo(bmpptr);

                                SaveDIBAs(@"C:\a.jpg", bmpptr, pixptr);
    }
```

Comment: It should be OK once you change your line `Gdip.SaveDIBAs(@"C:\", bmpptr, pixptr);` to `Gdip.SaveDIBAs(@"C:\a.jpg", bmpptr, pixptr);`

Comment: @KeyurPATEL i changed to .jpg but it didn't work

Comment: Check this out: [C# Save image without using Dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15886617/c-sharp-save-image-without-using-dialog). It is not completely relevant, but it shows that saving without dialog can be done, if you specify everything correctly. Try using `FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filePath);` as the answer in the link suggests, then `Gdip.SaveDIBAs(@"C:\" + fi.Name, bmpptr, pixptr);`

Comment: @KeyurPATEL so yes this is my problem in my question i want to find that way

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just simply use the built in `Image` and `Bitmap` types instead of directly calling the functions of the `gdip.dll`.

```
IntPtr img = (IntPtr)pics[i];
using (Bitmap bmp = Image.FromHBitmap(img))
{
     bmp.Save(@"C:\a.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

Comment: And if you add `using System.Drawing;`?

Comment: If you added the reference and it still cannot be resolved, then it might be a namespace or type conflict (do you have another `Image` type in your project?). Try to add the full namespace prefix in my code: `System.Drawing.Image.FromHBitmap`.

Comment: i try this one and it saved the image ,
                            Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(2450, 2450, 2452, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb, img);
                            newBitmap.Save(@"c:\"); .but when i open the image the image is  undermined

Comment: That `Bitmap` constructor awaits another pointer, which is the Scan0 inside of a `BitmapData`, If your pointer is a GDI+ bitmap, you should use the `System.Drawing.Image.FromHBitmap` method.

Comment: i don't have any assembly or system dll named System.Drawing.Image.FromHBitmap

Comment: The using clause should contain only `using System.Drawing;`. Now, `Bitmap` and `Image` types should be visible. But since you have problems with `Image`, I suspect you have a custom `Image` type somewhere in your project, which causes a conflict. To resolve this, you can either fully specify the `Image` type in my code: `bmp = System.Drawing.Image.FromHBitmap(img)`, OR, you should add an extra using clause to define an alias for the `Image` type: `using Image = System.Drawing.Image;`

Comment: Thank you but i get this error :A generic error occurred in GDI+.