# System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException

Tags: c#

When I try to save the modified image in the selected directory I get this exception ...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CFxC.png)

This is my code:

```
<code>https://pastebin.com/GqbB0Xb9</code>
```

But I can not figure out where I'm wrong

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15862810/a-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi-in-bitmap-save-method

Comment: Post code and error messages as text, not as images and links.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your modified code fully working :

First : when you save bitmaps into the new selected folder : the inside path was not obviously  existing in the selected output folder

2nd: When either a Bitmap object or an Image object is constructed from a file, the file remains locked for the lifetime of the object. As a result, you cannot change an image and save it back to the same file where it originated.

http://support.microsoft.com/?id=814675 ([A Generic error occurred in GDI+ in Bitmap.Save method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15862810/a-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi-in-bitmap-save-method))

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;


public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int[] size = new int[5] { 36, 24, 48, 72, 96 };
    private Bitmap one, two, three, four, five;
    private string[] path = new string[5] { "drawable-hdpi-", "drawable-mdpi-", "drawable-xhdpi-", "drawable-xxhdpi-", "drawable-xxxhdpi-" };
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult result = this.openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        // if a file is selected
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // Set the selected file URL to the textbox
            this.textBox1.Text = this.openFileDialog1.FileName;
        }
    }

    private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.textBox1.Text.Equals(""))
        {
            Resize(this.textBox1.Text, getFileName(this.textBox1.Text));
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Nessun file selezionato");
        }
    }

    private string getFileName(string text)
    {
        return Path.GetFileName(text) ;
    }

    private new void Resize(string text, string name)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(text);
        one = bitmap;
        two = bitmap;
        three = bitmap;
        four = bitmap;
        five = bitmap;
        one = ResizeImage(one, size[0], size[0]);
        two = ResizeImage(two, size[1], size[1]);
        three = ResizeImage(three, size[2], size[2]);
        four = ResizeImage(four, size[3], size[3]);
        five = ResizeImage(five, size[4], size[4]);
        SaveImage(one, two, three, four, five, name);
    }



private void SaveImage(Bitmap one, Bitmap two, Bitmap three, Bitmap four, Bitmap five, string name)
    {
        DialogResult folder = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (folder == DialogResult.OK && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath))
        {
            SaveIn(one, Path.Combine(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath,  path[0]+ name));
            SaveIn(two,  Path.Combine(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath , path[1] + name));
            SaveIn(three,  Path.Combine(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath , path[2]+name));
            SaveIn(four, Path.Combine(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath , path[3] +name));
            SaveIn(five, Path.Combine(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath , path[4] + name));
        CleanBmp(one);
        CleanBmp(two);
        CleanBmp(three);
        CleanBmp(four);
        CleanBmp(five);
    }

    }

private void CleanBmp(Bitmap bmp)
{
    bmp.Dispose();
    bmp = null;
}

private void SaveIn(Bitmap bmp, string v)
    {
        try
        {

        Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(bmp);

        newBitmap.Save(v);
        CleanBmp(newBitmap);

    }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("" + exc);
        }

    }

    public Bitmap ResizeImage(Bitmap image, int newWidth, int newHeight)
    {
        try
        {
            Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, Calculations(image.Width, image.Height, newWidth));

            using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
            {
                gr.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                gr.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                gr.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                gr.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(0, 0, newImage.Width, newImage.Height));

                var myBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(70, 205, 205, 205));

                double diagonal = Math.Sqrt(newImage.Width * newImage.Width + newImage.Height * newImage.Height);


                float slope = (float)(Math.Atan2(newImage.Height, newImage.Width) * 180 / Math.PI);

                gr.RotateTransform(slope);

                return newImage;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            throw exc;
        }
    }

    public int Calculations(decimal w1, decimal h1, int newWidth)
    {
        decimal height = 0;
        decimal ratio = 0;


        if (newWidth < w1)
        {
            ratio = w1 / newWidth;
            height = h1 / ratio;

            return (int)height;
        }

        if (w1 < newWidth)
        {
            ratio = newWidth / w1;
            height = h1 * ratio;
            return (int)height;
        }

        return (int)height;
    }
}
```