# C# MVC: Uploading Image works locally, fails on staging: A generic error occurred in GDI+

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, image-uploading

I have a form that includes a file-upload control. When testing locally I am successfully uploading the files to a location within my codebase. However, this does not work on our staging environment and I only have this generic error:

> **A generic error occurred in GDI+.**
>
> at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)

I have confirmed with the destination folder exists on the staging server and that it has write permissions. The image I'm testing with is only 200kb so it isn't maxing out on filesize.

```
private string SaveAssetFile(int assetId, HttpPostedFileBase assetFile, out string thumbnailPath)
    {
        string folderName = "/Content/Assets";
        string extension = "";
        string fileName = "";
        string thumbnailName = string.Format("asset{0}_thumb.jpg", assetId).ToLower();
        string fullPath = "";
        var format = ImageFormat.Jpeg;

        try
        {
            if (assetFile.ContentType.Contains("image"))
            {
                extension = assetFile.ContentType.Replace("image/", "");
                fileName = string.Format("asset{0}.{1}", assetId, extension).ToLower();
                fullPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~" + folderName), fileName);

                using (Image imgOriginal = Image.FromStream(assetFile.InputStream))
                {
                    switch (extension)
                    {
                        case "jpg":
                        case "jpeg":
                            format = ImageFormat.Jpeg;
                            break;
                        case "png":
                            format = ImageFormat.Png;
                            break;
                        case "gif":
                            format = ImageFormat.Gif;
                            break;
                        case "bmp":
                            format = ImageFormat.Bmp;
                            break;
                        default:
                            format = ImageFormat.Jpeg;
                            break;
                    }

                    imgOriginal.Save(fullPath, format);

                    // Do other stuff here
                }

                thumbnailPath = folderName + "/" + thumbnailName;

                return folderName + "/" + fileName;
            }
            else if (assetFile.ContentType.Contains("video"))
            {
                // Do other stuff here
            }
            else if (assetFile.ContentType.Contains("pdf"))
            {
                // Do other stuff here
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            // Error handling here

            throw ex;
        }

        thumbnailPath = null;
        return null;
    }
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: GDI exceptions should produce some messages in system event log, do you see them?

Comment: see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15862810/a-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi-in-bitmap-save-method

Comment: @RakeshKumar if it was related to that issue, would that not fail locally as well as on the staging server?