# How to get and save image to folder from listview

Tags: c#, listview

I need to get selected items from a ListView and copy them to a folder.

I select folder with images and then show them in the ListView. Now I need to get all the selected items and copy them into another selected folder.
Is there a way how to do it with better control then listview ?

I tried a few methods, but nothing works.

Comment: In method 2 maybe the filename is missing on destination folder. Are you getting exceptions? Which?

Comment: File.Copy want to String path, It was just an attempt
 's' is a selected item and cant be used like a path I think.
System.NotSupportedException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach:

```
int counter = 1;
        foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.SelectedItems)
        {
            var image = item.ImageList.Images[item.ImageKey]; //or imageIndex
            using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream($@"C:\temp\outputFileName_{counter}", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                {
                    image?.Save(memory, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    byte[] bytes = memory.ToArray();
                    fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                }
            }
            counter++;
        }
```

Comment: ImageKey doesn't work and imageindex return System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException

Comment: You are right! I've updated my answer! https://stackoverflow.com/a/15862892/4440491

Comment: I have still problems, Authorization.expection
And how will it work for more Images? ggg,jpeg will be name just for 1st image
FileMode.Create will delete old ggg.jpeg and create new with new image right ?

Comment: AuthenticationException - I'm guessing you will need to handle your saving credentials. And for saving file names you could use some kind of "template": savedImage_01.jpeg, savedImage_02.jpeg.... so with one image count variable.

Comment: Ok, authorization expectation isn't problem... But when I look at the image in the final folder, file have 0 bytes.

Comment: Do you have ImageList binded to the listview (Small/Large ImageList)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.
should be this: 
`for (int j = 0; j < imageList1.Images.Count; j++)
 {
                    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();    
                    item.ImageIndex = j;
                    imageList1.ImageSize = new Size(128, 128);    
                    listView1.LargeImageList = imageList1;    
                    listView1.Items.Add(item); 
 }`

Comment: Hmmm, yes, something like that. Then I would suggest to go through the code, line by line, with debugger. Have a look what your image object (in my code) actually is. I'm suspecting it is null.

Comment: Yes after, var image = item.ImageList.Images[item.ImageKey]; image is null
and fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length); Bytes[] is 0 and then leght is 0 too.

Comment: Ok, with imageindex it works. What to do with overiding in final folder ? i can give them index (i for example) and increase it, but every time i will start prog. again, images will override again.
Thank you for help

Comment: Use timestamp instead of index if you don't want to override them on every "export".