# iTextSharp: Use text and image as a SINGLE annotation

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have a piece of code that stamps a PDF by merging a FormXObject of a source pdf file. What I am trying to do is superimpose some text into that. How does one approach such operation?

1. **Add an image or merge a PDF to an existing document.**
2. **Add a text relative to that image/pdf.**
3. **Concatenate the text and image into one selectable annotation (ideally a stamp)**

I can do step one individually, but superimposing the text is what remains unclear. Think of it as trying to fake a signature using a stamp that contains modifiable text (similar to Adobe's Signature Appearance).

Comment: I don't have a solid answer for item #3, but you may be able to accomplish #2 this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826921/write-text-on-an-image-in-c-sharp