# Sending Image with center Text in it in Email

Tags: html, vb.net, email

Code to send email :

```
MailAddress addressFrom = new MailAddress("jack.du@e-iceblue.com", "Jack Du");
MailAddress addressTo = new MailAddress("susanwong32@outlook.com");
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(addressFrom, addressTo);

message.Date = DateTime.Now;
message.Subject = "Sending Email with HTML Body";
string htmlString = **my html code her to string convert**
                   ;   
message.BodyHtml = htmlString;

SmtpClient client= new SmtpClient();
client.Host = "smtp.outlook.com";
client.Port = 587;
client.Username = addressFrom.Address;
client.Password = "password";
client.ConnectionProtocols = ConnectionProtocols.Ssl;
client.SendOne(message);

Console.WriteLine("Sent Successfully!");
Console.Read();
```

I need to send email using Visual Basic .Net

**Issue** After Sending email i get my mail box having
 *My text shows below my image , while the below html code shows working correct*

Click to check my [html code](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FO223V1M4V6E)

Comment: When it comes to email you need to code it using tables and inline CSS. Some email clients like Outlook don't like divs. Once you have inline CSS and tables your email will work properly.

Comment: @Syfer thank i am checking for it..

Answer (score 1):

I will just use a background image in the container style, as follows

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    background: url('https://media.wmagazine.com/photos/585353e0d3b7a5db18f3a866/master/h_600,c_limit/GettyImages-105726097_master.jpg');
    text-align: center;
    color: orange;
    border: 1px solid #0d9ecf;
     width: 437px;
    height: 600px;
}
```

Instead of using the `<img>` tag.

Comment: please check it,as its showing fine in html but error in email

Comment: Support for background images in emails are very patchy. For example background images don't work in Outlook 2007 and above.

Comment: I tried it sending it to Hotmail, and it works if displayed inside Hotmail. In Outlook it may fail. Your best bet is to write text directly to the image before attaching it to the mail. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826921/write-text-on-an-image-in-c-sharp